# Select every hour query

Tags: influxdb

I have a simple weather station DB with example content:

```
time                humi1 humi2 light pressure station-id temp1 temp2
----                ----- ----- ----- -------- ---------- ----- -----
1530635257289147315 66    66    1834  1006     bee1       18.6  18.6
1530635317385229860 66    66    1832  1006     bee1       18.6  18.6
1530635377466534866 66    66    1829  1006     bee1       18.6  18.6
```

Station writes data every minute. I want to get `SELECT` not with all series, but just series written every hour (or every 60th series, simply said). How can I achieve it?

I tried to experiment with `...WHERE time % 60 = 0`, but it didn`t work. It seems, that `time` column doesnt permit any math operations (`/`, `%`, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by along with a one of the functions can do what you want:

`SELECT FIRST("humi1"), FIRST("humi2"), ... GROUP BY time(1h)`

I would imagine for most climate data you'd want the MEAN or MEDIAN rather than a single data point every hour

[basic example](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/data_exploration/#example-1-group-query-results-into-12-minute-intervals), and [more complex example](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/data_exploration/#example-2-limit-the-number-of-series-returned-and-include-a-group-by-time-clause)

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I want. I tried it incorrectly before: `SELECT "humi1" GROUP by time(1h)` and I got error `ERR: GROUP BY requires at least one aggregate function`. So, I didnt understand what influx wanted from me :)